# Updating Android SDKs (15 r 3) causes all built apks to crash when run

Tags: android, sdk

I just did one of those auto updates of the Android SDK (API 15 r3) and associated SDK tools.
Eclipse updates for the plugin as well.

Now nothing I run works. Every application gives the same type of initialization error:

ExceptionInInitialization error.

I am unable to revert; re-installs, workspace cleanouts, etc. I cannot get rid of it.
Unfortunately it seems the previous versions that I had were overwritten and unrecoverable.

Does anyone have any idea what went so bad? (I don't know if I will ever dare to do an
auto update again. Comrades at work have also suffered the same catastrophe.

HERE IS A STACK TRACE WHICH I NEGLECTED TO ADD.

```
03-23 18:24:36.578: E/AndroidRuntime(3090): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-23 18:24:36.578: E/AndroidRuntime(3090): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
03-23 18:24:36.578: E/AndroidRuntime(3090):     at com.lampreynetworks.ahd.oilbath.MeasurementLogActivity.onCreate(MeasurementLogActivity.java:66)
03-23 18:24:36.578: E/AndroidRuntime(3090):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-23 18:24:36.578: E/AndroidRuntime(3090):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-23 18:24:36.578: E/AndroidRuntime(3090):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
03-23 18:24:36.578: E/AndroidRuntime(3090):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
03-23 18:24:36.578: E/AndroidRuntime(3090):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-23 18:24:36.578: E/AndroidRuntime(3090):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
03-23 18:24:36.578: E/AndroidRuntime(3090):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-23 18:24:36.578: E/AndroidRuntime(3090):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-23 18:24:36.578: E/AndroidRuntime(3090):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-23 18:24:36.578: E/AndroidRuntime(3090):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-23 18:24:36.578: E/AndroidRuntime(3090):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-23 18:24:36.578: E/AndroidRuntime(3090):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-23 18:24:36.578: E/AndroidRuntime(3090):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-23 18:24:36.578: E/AndroidRuntime(3090):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-23 18:24:36.578: E/AndroidRuntime(3090): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.lampreynetworks.ahd.oxp.Nomenclature
03-23 18:24:36.578: E/AndroidRuntime(3090):     at com.lampreynetworks.ahd.oilbath.MeasurementAdapter.<clinit>(MeasurementAdapter.java:82)
03-23 18:24:36.578: E/AndroidRuntime(3090):     ... 15 more
```

Comment: Do you mean `ExceptionInInitializerError`?

Comment: yes I do. I will get a stack trace.

Comment: Does the class `com.lampreynetworks.ahd.oxp.Nomenclature` exist in your project and does it compile without errors? Is this one of your classes or something from a library you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's been a change to the dependency management system. Xavier Durochet posted a [Google+ item](https://plus.google.com/u/0/109385828142935151413/posts/RL91VJd1yti) about it.

It looks like `com.lampreynetworks.ahd.oxp.Nomenclature` was in `Referenced Libraries` in your project. It now needs to be located only under `Android Dependencies`. You can remove the Referenced Libraries dependency from the Libraries tab under the project's Properties > Java Build Path

Also, the `lib` directory should be changed to `libs`.

In case the Google+ item gets deleted at some point, it links to a [blog post](http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17) and a [post on tools.android.com](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects) which I am linking here for completeness.

Comment: I followed the item you posed above and it solved my problem.  THANX!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you update the tools as well as the SDK?  I believe that the new SDK requires ADT 17.

Comment: Yes, everything was done. The Android SDK manager does all that for you and then Eclipse goes and does the rest (after being told to do by the SDK manager).